# ServerSocket doesn't open the port on WAN(internet) But works correctly on local network

Tags: android, sockets, networking, serversocket

I want to send a socket from one android device to another

this is my *sender* code :

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ReceiverIP, 6666), 10000);
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(message);
socket.close();
```

and this is my *receiver* :

```
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);
Socket resultSocket=ss.accept();
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(resultSocket.getInputStream());
String stringresult=dis.readUTF();
ss.close();
```

and android permissions :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

on my local network this code works correctly with local ip addresses but when I use the external ip on internet connection the receiver can not open the port and SocketTimeoutException occurs on sender class.
I tried to use DatagramSocket (UDP protocol) but it had the same problem on WAN network.
what should I do to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: You could be clearer about the network topology for the case in which it is failing but most likely your service provider (or your own modem/NAT/router/firewall if involved) is blocking or unable to route the incoming connection request from the outside world.

Comment: thank you for your reply but If there is some restriction on my network why several internet and communication apps (like viber,skype,...) work correctly on my network?finally how they work?

Comment: They use an intermediate server either to exchange the data, or to play the "firewall piercing" trick in the hope that the clients will then be able to exchange data directly.

Comment: Strange story that your receiver (the server) cannot open that port. The server is not aware of LAN or WAN. What kind or error gives the server? If a client cannot connect then did you forward that port on your router?

Comment: To address your title, ServerSocket opens a port on the localhost. If you want your WAN address to map to that, or admit connections, you probably have some router work to do.

Comment: No I didn't try any router works,I want to have a peer to peer connection and I don't want to ask final users to change their network,after your replies I think tcp/udp isnot the appropriate protocol to use,maybe XMPP is a better Choice.